# How to connect mobile notifications to laptop

Tags: android

When mobile has some notifications Immediately the Laptop should recognize the notifications and should display those .

I want to know how could I implement it
Any Help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are many ways to do it.This is how I might do.
//Logic Only//
Laptop should be connected to wifi. Whenever user gets notification then that notification should be uploaded to a server(or sent as a sms to server if internet not available)  and then sent to laptop.Then the laptop should display it.